# flutter doctor - Error: Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine

Tags: git, dart

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Android SDK, Git already installed. Flutter git was cloned successfully.
2. Running `flutter doctor` in PowerShell

**Logs**

```
C:\flutter>flutter doctor
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ead227f...
Start-BitsTransfer : flutter doctor - 69/5000 The resource loader cache doesn't have a loaded MUI entry . (HRESULT: 0x80073B01 Exception)
En C:\flutter\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1: 47 Character: 1

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $dartSdkUrl -Destination $dartSdkZip
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], COMException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Mana
 gement.NewBitsTransferCommand

Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...

Waiting 2 seconds, press CTRL+C to exit ...
```

I'm using NTLM auth behind corporate proxy.

Comment: did you set you path for environment variable and reboot the system or not.

Comment: Your corporate proxy does have a transparent SSL traffic inspection?

Comment: @krishankTripathi thing is I haven't see them (env-vars), In case of, I've read an issue about case-sensitive problem with sdk path. Could be this a problem???

Comment: @shadowsheep I don't really know too much about proxy structure. I just know is NTLM-based auth.

Comment: Check that the environment variable has been set correctly, check your firewall settings, make sure that [BITS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968799(v=vs.85).aspx) is also enabled.

Comment: What environment variables?? flutter's. You mean add to path

Comment: @PedroMora yes, adding it to the PATH under Advanced Settings.

Comment: I keep getting the same error on a MAC environment

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue, what I did is uninstalling the flutter SDK by removing the directory where it installed and then installing it again, it worked as you can see below.

I think the last update caused this issue.

[image: It worked]

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you **disable** BITS [Background Task Infrastructure service]

type "Services" on **Cortana**  then click on services > then go to >Background Task Infrastructure service> Enable and start it > Then reboot your laptop

It will help you to solve this error...

BITS related errors can be solved by just enabling **Background Task Infrastructure service**

Comment: its status is "Running" all time and I can't change it

Answer (score 1):

### This is how you can fix it :

Open Control Panel – System – Advanced system settings
and click on the button ***Environment Variables***.

---

If environment variable **ComSpec** is set to anything other than **%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe** expanding usually to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, then reset it to Windows default **%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe**.

Answer (score 1):

Try git reset command if you are facing issue with Downloading Dart SDK

```
git reset head --hard
```

After this flutter doctor command will work fine:

```
flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer to make it more accessible for those coming from Google. If you are on Windows 8, and this error is all you have a glimpse of before the terminally shuts down, see this answer [Flutter update causing error "Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer" irrecoverable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652144/flutter-update-causing-error-flutter-requires-powershell-5-0-or-newer-irrecove)

In a nutshell, locate your flutter installation and set the powershell version to 3 (the default that came with the OS). If you no longer recall the install location, run `where flutter dart` from your terminal. After this is revealed, navigate to "bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1" and update the line "$psMajorVersionRequired = 5" to 3