# Flutter update causing error "Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer" irrecoverable

Tags: powershell, flutter, windows-8

After I updated flutter (using "flutter update") I start getting an error

> Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer

And on my Windows 8, I am not able to install PowerShell 5.0. It is throwing an error

> The update is not applicable

Now I just want to revert back to older version of flutter (which was working on my system). But I am not able to figure out which flutter version that was working on my PC before upgrade, and which version it became after upgrading. Because for all command line params, flutter is just giving above mentioned PowerShell version error and is quitting.

Flutter is stuck after upgrade. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found that in this script `bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1` there is variable `$psMajorVersionRequired = 5` I just made it's value 3 and flutter seems working so far.
Now "flutter doctor" shows me version 1.22.5 (and as I can see it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases) it is latest as of now)

Comment: Instead of cheating your flutter installation you should urgently upgrade your OS to at least Windows 8.1 or better to Windows 10 and then update Powershell to version 5.1. Alternativly you could install Powershell version 7.1 as this will install next to the Windows Powershell version.

Comment: @Olaf: There are lots of other software's running for years on this PC. Just for flutter dependency, I wouldn't jeopardies the whole system by upgrading it's OS. By the tweak I mentioned, flutter is running and building apps successfully. That simply means flutter either doesn't really need PS5 or it might need it for specific purpose which I might not came across when building my apps. On the contrary, carefully designed software checks for prerequisite and tell user right before installation or upgrade. Flutter was needing me to upgrade my OS for telling its own version after upgrade.

Comment: Of course this is your decision but you are working with an unsupported OS. Windows 8 does not get updates for 5 years now. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: If you are struggling to locate your flutter installation, run `where flutter dart`. That would lead you to where to make the update in this answer

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and this was the solution, thank you `$psMajorVersionRequired = 2`

It seems like lazy programming from Google's side. If flutter works with Windows 7 then there's no reason for them to add this one flag

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this issue, in my case it was resolved updating Powershell, I'm currently using Windows 8.1. I downloaded following these steps:

1. Go to -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2
2. Clic on Download PowerShell.
3. After that will show you a github page and you'll have to download the version needed to your system.

I hope that works for you!