# how do i completely install flutter dart sdk ,

Tags: flutter, dart, path, sdk

I tried opening a flutter project, yet it says flutter sdk download incomplete, and each time i run flutter doctor, it gives me this error:

[image: Downloading dart sdk failed]

This was the error:

> [Checking Dart SDK version...  Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter
> engine 3950c6140a3f1cb295364b0446627bd3a1736915... Downloading the
> Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest...
> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved:
> 'storage.googleapis.com' At C:\Users\joan uchechi
> okereke\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:70 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dartSdkUrl -OutFile $dartSdkZip
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>     WebException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
>     Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying... ]

I tried deleting the flutter sdk i had and downloading a new one. Appending the path in the environment variable , yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not use images. Please just post the text of the error.

Comment: Are you extracting the folder?

Comment: Yes, i extracted the folder already

Comment: @Apealed i added the error text to the question just now

Comment: Can you see if this resolves your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541672/9727402

Comment: I did that, BITS is enabled and i restarted my system but it still didn't solve the issue

Comment: I resolved it by refreshing my windows and then creating a new Dart variable in the User variables . Then I specified the dart\bin part that is contained in the flutter\bin . And updated the flutter\bin in the Path variable. After running flutter doctor, it worked , but because I was use android Electric eel version, I got an error couldn't find bundled Java version. Then I went to \Application\Android\android studio\jre  file and deleted it because it contained a single empty file . Then I duplicated the jbr file in it, and renamed it to jre. That solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by refreshing my windows and then creating a new variable in env variables that I named Dart and I specified the *dart\bin* path that is contained in the *flutter\bin.*

Then I ensured the path to flutter/bin was correct.
After running flutter doctor, it worked , but because I was used android Electric eel version, I got an error
-*couldn't find bundled Java version*.
Then I went to *\Application\Android\android studio\jre* and deleted it because it contained a single empty file . Then I duplicated the jbr file in it, and renamed it to jre. That solved my issue.

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).